# Javascript/Html Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment; Uncaught ReferenceError: Calc is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting the invalid left hand assignment error and the undefined function error. Anyone able to help me? It's basically a calculator.

```js
//Calc.js: 
var FirstNum = document.getElementById('FirstNum')
var SecondNum = document.getElementById('SecondNum')
var Method = document.getElementById('Method')
var Answer = document.getElementById('Answer')
 
function Calc() {
    if(Method.value == add) {
        FirstNum.value + SecondNum.value = Answer.value
        alert(Answer)
    } else {
        if(Method.value == subtract) {
            FirstNum.value - SecondNum.value = Answer.value
            alert(Answer)
        } else if (Method.value == multiply ){
            FirstNum.value * SecondNum.value = Answer.value
            alert(Answer)
        } else if(Method.value == divide) {
            Firstnum.value / SecondNum.value = Answer.value
            alert(Answer)
        } else {
            alert("ERROR. You broke it :(")
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table border='1' align=center>
    <tr align=center><td><b>First Number</b></td> <td><b>Second Number</b></td></tr>
    <tr align=center>
        <td align=center><input type="text" id="FirstNum" align=center></td>
        <td align=center><input type="text" id="SecondNum" align=center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Method" value="add">+</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Method" value="subtract">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Method" value="multiply">*</td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="Method" value="divide">/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align=center><input type="button" value="=" onclick=Calc()></input></td>
        <td align=center><input type="text" id="Answer" align=center></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: first format your code

Comment: Where is the variable `subtract` supposed to be coming from? Why do you expect the DOM to be ready before it's loaded? What does the console tell you?

Comment: FirstNum.value + SecondNum.value = Answer.value?

Comment: ^ Yeah, that don't make no sense.

Comment: Like I said, I'm pretty new, what should I write instead?

Comment: I don't know, what do you *want* to write instead? What is that line supposed to do? Obviously assigning a value to an addition operation is nonsensical.

Comment: @Steve I just put that thing into a beautifier myself as well, but this line: `alert(Answer)` was misplaced between an `if` and an `else`. That also seems like a syntax error.

Comment: @JohnWhite I saw that and assumed it was meant to be in the `if`block. It's not the cause of the problem though.

Comment: I'm trying to make is work like a calculator. I assumed I would need to assign the variables

Comment: In an assignment operation using `=`, the value of the *right hand side* is assigned *to the left hand side*. Are you simply confusing sides here...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your error is basically the assignment direction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <table border='1' align="center">

        <tr align="center">
            <td><b>First Number</b></td>
            <td><b>Second Number</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" id="FirstNum" align="center"></td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" id="SecondNum" align="center"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Method" value="add">+</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Method" value="subtract">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Method" value="multiply">*</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Method" value="divide">/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Calc()"></input></td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" id="Answer" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <script>
                //Calc.js:  
            var FirstNum = document.getElementById('FirstNum')
            var SecondNum = document.getElementById('SecondNum')
            var Method = document.getElementsByName('Method')
            var Answer = document.getElementById('Answer')
            function getRadioValue(theRadioGroup)
            {
                var elements = document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup);
                for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
                {
                    if (elements[i].checked)
                    {
                        return elements[i].value;
                    }
                }
            }
            function Calc(){

                if(getRadioValue("Method") == "add"){
                    Answer.value = parseFloat(FirstNum.value) + parseFloat(SecondNum.value) ;

                } else{
                    if(getRadioValue("Method") == "subtract"){
                    Answer.value = parseFloat(FirstNum.value) - parseFloat(SecondNum.value);

                    }else
                        if(getRadioValue("Method") == "multiply"){
                            Answer.value = parseFloat(FirstNum.value) * parseFloat(SecondNum.value) ;

                        } else
                            if(getRadioValue("Method") == "divide"){
                                Answer.value = parseFloat(FirstNum.value) / parseFloat(SecondNum.value) ;

                                }   
                            else{
                                    alert("ERROR. You broke it :(")             

                    }
                }
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the Test2.html:33 "Uncaught ReferenceError: Calc is not defined" error.

Comment: @JustinWeaver, Have you tried my entire solution? I've not just corrected assignment error, but whole bunch of script errors. There were problem in closing the condition, etc.

Comment: I've done it now, can you explain the solution, so I could learn from it?

Comment: @JustinWeave, the one that i've posted as answer.